# Qwt: Axis Border Dist?

Tags: qt, qt4, axis, qwt

I have two plots which has created by using qwt. But I couldn't sync their axis(xBottom) with each other.

[image]

They both have (30,30) BorderDist

```
plot1->axisWidget(QwtPlot::xBottom)->setMinBorderDist(30,30) //distance between axis and border
```

but only upper plot apply this function and there is a difference between axises.

How can I solve this?

Regards.

Comment: Hi, can you post a full compilation project that reproduce the problem ? You can use some appropriate website ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Axis numbers cause this problem. İf I give enough space(border) bewtween label and canvas side, everything is great.

Like this:

```
const int margin = 30;
plot1->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin( margin, QwtPlot::yLeft );
plot1->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin( margin, QwtPlot::yRight );
plot2->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin( margin, QwtPlot::yLeft );
plot2->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin( margin, QwtPlot::yRight );
```

Thanks Uwe for help.